# Updating Struct variables on a singleton instance

Tags: swift

I am trying to update a locally stored feature flag values on my singleton instance based on the UI changes and having trouble implementing a solution. Any help here is much appreciated.

The following is the singleton class that gets instantiated during app launch and the Featureflag values are read from remote and is cached in the "cachedKillSwitchValues" attribute. I have also detailed the implementation of the "KillSwitchValuesCacheEntry" and the "KillSwitches" struct as well.

The feature flag values are displayed in the debug screen of the app so we can override the remote values by toggling them. When this happens I have to override the cachedKillSwitchValues to retain the changes.

On the UI I convert the KillSwitches() object into "var tableData: [(String, Bool)] = []" so it becomes easier to load the table View data . The challenge is I am confused on how to update the cachedKillSwitchValues since my updateLocalKillSwitchCache(key: String, value: Bool) requires a string and a bool argument while I see the only way to update the KillSwitches are by accessing the attribute directly. I took a shot at coding the update method but couldn't complete.

```
public final class AppConfigurationRepository {

    public static let shared = AppConfigurationRepository()
    private var cachedKillSwitchValues: KillSwitchValuesCacheEntry?

    private init() {
      cachedKillSwitchValues = KillSwitchValuesCacheEntry(entryItem: KillSwitches(), lastUpdateMetaDate: Date())
      }

    public func updateLocalKillSwitchCache(key: String, value: Bool) {
        // The code below is wrong, tried implementing multiple ways but went no where.
        var killSwithDict = cachedKillSwitchValues?.entryData.dictionary()
        killSwithDict?.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
        cachedKillSwitchValues?.entryData = killSwithDict as KillSwitches
    }

}
```

```
struct KillSwitchValuesCacheEntry: Codable {
    var entryData: KillSwitches
    let remoteConfigLastUpdateDate: Date

    init(entryItem: KillSwitches, lastUpdateMetaDate: Date) {
        self.entryData = entryItem
        self.remoteConfigLastUpdateDate = lastUpdateMetaDate
    }
}
```

```
public struct KillSwitches: Codable {

    public var featureA: Bool = true
    public var featureB: Bool = true


    public enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case featureA
        case featureB
    }

    init() { }
}
```

Comment: `entryData.dictionary()`, there is no dictionary in your code?

Comment: Sorry edited the code. Tried implementing the solution but was not successful. I would rather delete the code instead of confusing others.